# Convering lists with float for pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

This is my first time to post question and I am new to python. I've tried to plug 'list1' and 'list2' to 'x' and 'y' in the formula below and errors occurs like

> ('Could not convert
>   1.16041.16001.16351.17491.17661.17501.17461.17471.1779 to numeric')

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
from pandas import *

list1 = ['1.1575', '1.1604', '1.1600', '1.1635', '1.1749', '1.1766', '1.1750', '1.1746', '1.1747', '1.1779']
list2 = ['6604.11341382', '6688.01480364', '6668.72146384', '6553.56452794', '6499.18728419', '6629.18122154', '6724.42744078', '6737.98000228', '6755.31691870', '6556.66000350']

# Method 2 (Correlation, p-value)
def pcc(x,y):
    x = x - x.mean(0)
    y = y - y.mean(0)
    x /= x.std(0)
    y /= y.std(0)
    return np.mean(x*y)

x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)
print(linregress(x,y))
```

Comment: Your x y values are strings. You need to convert them to float before applying regression

Comment: `list(map(float,list1))`

Comment: Also note you are passing the entire list as `x` so `x - x.mean(0)` is trying to subtract `x.mean` from an entire list of values, not sure that will work

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this bellow the initialization of list1 and 2:

```
list1 = [ float(z) for z in list1 ]
list2 = [ float(z) for z in list2 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[float(i) for i in list1]
```

it creates a new list with float values.

Hope its Help.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
list1 = ['1.1575', '1.1604', '1.1600', '1.1635', '1.1749', '1.1766', '1.1750', '1.1746', '1.1747', '1.1779']
list2 = ['6604.11341382', '6688.01480364', '6668.72146384', '6553.56452794', '6499.18728419', '6629.18122154', '6724.42744078', '6737.98000228', '6755.31691870', '6556.66000350']

list1=list(map(float,list1)) #convert into float
list2=list(map(float,list2))
# Method 2 (Correlation, p-value)
def pcc(x,y):
    x = x - x.mean(0)
    y = y - y.mean(0)
    x /= x.std(0)
    y /= y.std(0)
    return np.mean(x*y)
print(pcc(np.array(list1),np.array(list2))) # pass numpy array
```

Output:

```
0.04183992052616166
```

OR 
Better keep everything in numpy array

```
import numpy as np
list1 = ['1.1575', '1.1604', '1.1600', '1.1635', '1.1749', '1.1766', '1.1750', '1.1746', '1.1747', '1.1779']
list2 = ['6604.11341382', '6688.01480364', '6668.72146384', '6553.56452794', '6499.18728419', '6629.18122154', '6724.42744078', '6737.98000228', '6755.31691870', '6556.66000350']

list1 = np.array(list1).astype(np.float) # or np.asarray(list1, dtype=np.float64)
list2 = np.array(list2).astype(np.float)
# Method 2 (Correlation, p-value)
def pcc(x,y):
    x = x - x.mean(0)
    y = y - y.mean(0)
    x /= x.std(0)
    y /= y.std(0)
    return np.mean(x*y)
print(pcc(list1,list2)) # directly pass numpy float arrays
```

Output

```
0.04183992052616166
```